# Why can I use a lambda expression in place of a callback delegate?

Tags: c#, .net, syntax

I discovered some new C# syntax and do not understand what it means. Here is the syntax-related code:

1)

```
BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        PopulateUI(ds);
    }));
```

2)

```
private void OnFormLoad() 
{ 
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(() => GetSqlData()); 
}
```

What is the meaning of `new Action()` and what is the meaning of the `=>` symbol?

The syntax of `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` was `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(PrintOut), "Hello");` but here it shows `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(() => GetSqlData());`, so how does it work? Why is `WaitCallback` missing? Please explain in detail.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: *() => some_code* is a lambda expression and is just a shortcut for writing anonymous delegates. i think your confusion is caused by too many ways to achieve the same thing.

Comment: @Pauli Østerø: Very well said :)

Comment: `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(() => GetSqlData());` doesn't compile in my test app.  Which version of the .NET framework is your project using (or at least, which version of VS)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at

[Action Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx)

> Encapsulates a method that has a
>   single parameter and does not return a
>   value. You can use the Action
>   delegate to pass a method as a
>   parameter without explicitly declaring
>   a custom delegate.

and

and [Lambda Expressions (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

> A lambda expression is an anonymous
>   function that can contain expressions
>   and statements, and can be used to
>   create delegates or expression tree
>   types.
>
> All lambda expressions use the lambda
>   operator =>, which is read as "goes
>   to". The left side of the lambda
>   operator specifies the input
>   parameters (if any) and the right side
>   holds the expression or statement
>   block. The lambda expression x => x *
>   x is read "x goes to x times x."

Answer (score 6):

As others have said, it is a lambda, which is basically an anonymous (unnamed) local function.

This might make a bit more sense if you look at some similar code that doesn't use lambdas:

```
// With a lambda
private void OnFormLoad()
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(() => GetSqlData()); 
}

// Without a lambda
private void OnFormLoad() 
{ 
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ExecuteGetSqlData);
}

private void ExecuteGetSqlData()
{
    // If GetSqlData returns something, change this to "return GetSqlData();"
    GetSqlData();
}
```

As for the other code, normally you shouldn't have to do `new Action`.  The problem is that the `BeginInvoke` method takes a `Delegate`, which is sort of old school, and breaks how most new code works.

With newer code (that takes something like `Action`, or a specific type of delegate, like `WaitCallback`), you either write a lambda, or simply give the name of a function inside your class.  The example code I wrote above demonstrates both of these.

Also note that if you see something like: `(Action) (() => Blah())`, it is pretty much the same as `new Action(() => Blah())`.

Answer (score 4):

These are known as [lambda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx), which aren't very different from delegates in C#.

The empty `()` mean there are no arguments, and what's between the (optional) `{}` are the lambda expression bodies. The `=>` operator simply associates both expressions together to make a lambda expression. As an aside, they're commonly found in LINQ code.

There's nothing special about `new Action()`, just that it's a [delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) that can map a lambda expression to itself.

As for `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()`, the `WaitCallback` argument is a delegate. You can either pass the name of a named delegate as the argument, pass an anonymous `delegate` object or write a lambda expression for this anonymous `delegate` (in your case it's `() => GetSqlData()`).

Answer (score 2):

[Lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

[Action Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx)